# How do I add multiple select options

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add rounds 1, 2,3 on multiple select options i.e. **Round 1 + Round 5** as selected on the image below, and display on id="total" which will be **6**? I have tried but not getting the idea.

HTML form

```
<div class="form row">

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="no_of_rounds">
    <option value="1">Round 1</option>
    <option value="2">Round 2</option>
    <option value="3">Round 3</option>
    <option value="4">Round 4</option>
    <option value="5">Round 5</option>
    <option value="6">Round 6</option>
    <option value="7">Round 7</option>
    <option value="8">Round 8</option>
    <option value="9">Pay 1st Round - 8th Round</option>
</select>
<input id="total" type="text"> 
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
   document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('change', function() {
    const nr = +document.getElementById('no_of_rounds').value || 0;
    var round_1 = 80;
    var round_2 = 90;
    var round_3 = 100;
    var round_4 = 110;
 
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
  }


}
$('select').selectpicker();
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: See the documentation; use e.g. [`selectedOptions`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions).

Comment: How will the `DIV.form` actually change?

Comment: You have a div with class form. Then the closing tag is a form tag. Then you use `change` eventListener on the `div.form`  ? To add to the confusion you have this `How do I add rounds 1, 2,3 on click rounds or rounds and display on id="total"?` . I mean, i personally don't understand what you actually want to do.

Comment: I have updated what I actually want, `div.form`  is used in `document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('change', function()` to fire instant change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```js
document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let selectedValues = $('#no_of_rounds').val();
  
  let sum = 0;
  $("#no_of_rounds option:selected").each(function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    if ($this.length) {
      sum += parseInt($this.val());
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form row">

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="no_of_rounds">
    <option value="1">Round 1</option>
    <option value="2">Round 2</option>
    <option value="3">Round 3</option>
    <option value="4">Round 4</option>
    <option value="5">Round 5</option>
    <option value="6">Round 6</option>
    <option value="7">Round 7</option>
    <option value="8">Round 8</option>
    <option value="9">Pay 1st Round - 8th Round</option>
</select>
<input id="total" type="text"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted to add values in rounds lets say Round 1 has value 1 and Round 5 has value 5; the result should be 6;

Comment: Just modified code to what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version pure JS that works well :

```js
const no_of_rounds = document.querySelector("#no_of_rounds")

//listening to changes
no_of_rounds.addEventListener('change',(event) => {
  
  //getting all checked values
  const valuesSelected = no_of_rounds.selectedOptions
  
  //summing up all the values
  const sum = Array.from(valuesSelected).map(({ value }) => parseInt(value)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  
  //changing the value
  document.querySelector("#total").value = sum

})
```

```html
<div class="form row">

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="no_of_rounds">
    <option value="1">Round 1</option>
    <option value="2">Round 2</option>
    <option value="3">Round 3</option>
    <option value="4">Round 4</option>
    <option value="5">Round 5</option>
    <option value="6">Round 6</option>
    <option value="7">Round 7</option>
    <option value="8">Round 8</option>
    <option value="9">Pay 1st Round - 8th Round</option>
</select>
<input id="total" type="text"> 
</div>
```

for the row `const sum = Array.from(valuesSelected).map(({ value }) => parseInt(value)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);` what i'm doing is :

**Getting all the values** with `const valuesSelected = no_of_rounds.selectedOptions`

**Changing the type to an array** to manipulate it : `Array.from(valuesSelected)`

**Mapping the values** to get only values and parsing these to Integers : `map(({ value }) => parseInt(value))`

**Summing the values** to get the total : `reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You Have to declare global scope variable and add the value accordingly.
Like this.

```
<script>
   var totalValue = 0;
   document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('change', function() {
    totalValue = totalValue + (document.getElementById('no_of_rounds').value || 0);
    var round_1 = 80;
    var round_2 = 90;
    var round_3 = 100;
    var round_4 = 110;
 
    document.getElementById('total').value = totalValue;
  }


}
$('select').selectpicker();
</script>
```